# Where do you put the form element if you have editable rows of a table in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have a table(A) and we want a specific row to become editable on click.  Currently we have a directive that inserts a new table into the td of table(A) where it is called.  We do this so we can use the `<form>` element around the table.

#### uneditable-table.html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td ng-show="editing" class="editing" colspan="2">
           <div edit-form-directive
             model="thing"
             on-success="thingUpdated(thing); editing=false;"
             on-cancel="editing=false; setUpdating(false);"
             enabled="editing" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### edit-template.html inserted via the editFormDirective

```
 <form ng-submit="save(thingCopy)" name="EditForm">
      <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td>
                <input ng-model="thing.field1"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <input ng-model="thing.field2"/>
              </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
      <table>
    </form>
```

#### Question:

We have tried putting the `<form>` element around each row to be editable, and this works, however, this is not semantically correct with the `<form>` around a `<tr>` within a table.

We also considered putting the `<form>` around the entire table in `uneditable-table.html`.  This causes a form validation issue, where we may have many errors per non-unique form node, so we would have to index the nodes to get specific errors.

We settled on the code as it is here, with having the `<form>` element around a whole new table (in `edit-template.html`) and inserting that into a `<td>`, as this seemed the least harmful.

We do have to have the form tag so we can access validation based on the form name and nodes.

Is there a more Angular (or elegant) way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Angular way. Form tag isn't needed:

```
<table ng-form="EditForm">
    ...
</table>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngForm